# calling to constuctor using(along with) realloc

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, constructor

i'm writing my own type of std::vector for homework assignments,using class templates.
i wan't it to be efficient as possible so i prefer to use realloc function rather then new.
this causes me a problem because when i allocate memory to new member it doesn't call to the constructor of the new member and these causes a lot of problems.

the relevant part of my class template:

```
template<class T>
class myVec {
    T *m_data;
    unsigned m_size;
public:
    //some methods
    //some methods
    myVec<T>& resize(unsigned size) {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            delete[] m_data;
            m_data = nullptr;
            m_size = 0;
            return *this;
        }
        m_data = (T*)realloc(m_data, size * sizeof(T));  //should call to constructor of T here!
        m_size = size;
        return *this;
    };
    void push(const T& t) {
        m_data = (T*)realloc(m_data, ++m_size * sizeof(T));
        memcpy(m_data, &t, sizeof(t));
        //m_data[m_size - 1] = t;
    };
    ~myVec() { delete[] m_data; };
};
```

Does it wrong to use realloc(from C like malloc and free) along with new and delete?
if so, is there realloc like function for c++ that calls to constructor?
if not,how can i call manually call to the constructor after the allocation?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` and `realloc` in C++ - it just doesn't work with C++ `class`es

Comment: You cannot mix the `*alloc` family of functions with `new` and `delete`

Comment: Also mixing `realloc` with `delete[]` is indeed straight up wrong and means your code invokes *undefined behavior*. You need to allocate the new array with `new[]` (there is no `realloc` like functionality)

Comment: *i wan't it to be efficient as possible* -- Leave that to the experts.  Writing such classes to be as efficient as possible requires extensive experience with C++.  The best you will probably do is to get the vector class to work properly, and as mentioned, using `realloc` is not the way to go about accomplishing this.

Comment: great,you cant mix realloc with new, so there is convenient alternative to realloc in c++? all is written in the question post above, if you will always say leave it to the expert you will never become a expert by yourself

Comment: You have to use `new[]` throughout.  There is no `realloc` in C++ that works with non-POD types.

Comment: There's nothing like `realloc` because of stuff like `std::vector`.

Comment: but using new[] forces my to copy the entire new vector to new location with all of it content. and if it is really big vector that grows consistently? it will be super inefficient...

Comment: @EliavLouski -- *if you will always say leave it to the expert you will never become a expert by yourself* -- So why not look at how `std::vector` is implemented?  Just open the header file and see for yourself the type of coding required to have vector as efficient as possible.  Are you ready to take on that challenge?  Start out walking first, not attempt to do a marathon.

Comment: Your assumption that `realloc` is more efficient than moving to a `new[]` array has to be proven first - you are just assuming that it is inefficient, without benchmarking

Comment: @EliavLouski Your vector class lacks a `capacity` member to keep track of the maximum number of entries that can be filled without reallocation.  That is a major aspect that is missing from your vector class.  You want efficiency, but you didn't factor that in your design.  Every time `push` is called, you're calling `realloc` -- that is not efficient (granted that `realloc` will not work anyway).

Comment: `realloc` can avoid copying, for example when the new buffer is in the same spot as the old buffer, but the rest of the time it's copying the old buffer to the new buffer just like `vector`. And I'm betting somewhere in the bowels of `vector` it's pulling the similar copy avoidance tricks `realloc` uses. You may find it worth your time to look into *placement `new`*.

Comment: By the way, having your own `vector` is great in school. I salute you for thinking of it.  You never know when you'll run into a "Perform this trivial task the hard way" assignment. Save you a buttload of time if you've already solved the hard way.

Comment: @EliavLouski Yes, we aren't discouraging you from creating your own vector class, just that there are some basic things you're missing, such as what has been mentioned so far.  You're also missing copy constructor and assignment operators.  Efficiency shouldn't be the goal -- just get your vector class to work correctly and consistently (i.e. no bugs).

Comment: @Paul just beat me to the Rule of Three warning. Here's a link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three . Rule of Five isn't as important for stability, but if you want fast, it's pretty much essential.

Comment: @EliavLouski -- Using `realloc` a `myVec<std::string>` would fail miserably.  That is just to summarize everything that is being said so far concerning the usage of `realloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()` with `new`/`delete`. Use one or the other.

If you insist on manually allocating the array using the C runtime functions, you will have to use [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to manually call C++ constructors AFTER you have allocated the array.  And, as such, you will have to manually call C++ destructors.

Also, it is not safe for your `push()` to use `memcpy()` for non-POD types, either.  You need to implement proper copy/move semantics for pushed elements.

And, don't forget the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) so your class implements proper copy/move semantics for itself, too.

Try something more like this instead:

```
template<class T>
class myVec
{
    T *m_data = nullptr;
    unsigned m_size = 0;

public:
    ...

    myVec() = default;

    myVec(const myVec<T> &src)
    {
        if (src.m_size)
        {
            m_data = (T*) malloc(src.m_size * sizeof(T));
            if (!m_data) throw std::runtime_error("malloc failed!");

            for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
                new (&m_data[i]) T(src.m_data[i]);

            m_size = src.m_size;
        }
    }

    myVec(myVec<T> &&src)
    {
        std::swap(m_data, src.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size, src.m_size);
    }

    ~myVec()
    {
        resize(0);
    }

    void resize(unsigned size)
    {
        if (m_size != size)
        {
            T *temp;

            if (size)
            {
                temp = (T*) malloc(size * sizeof(T));
                if (!temp) throw std::runtime_error("malloc failed!");
            }
            else
                temp = nullptr;

            unsigned numToMove = std::min(m_size, size);

            for(unsigned i = 0; i < numToMove; ++i)
                new (&temp[i]) T(std::move(m_data[i]));

            if (size < m_size)
            {
                for(unsigned i = m_size; i-- > size; )
                    m_data[i].~T();
            }
            else
            {
                for(unsigned i = m_size; i < size; ++i)
                    new(&temp[i]) T();
            }

            free(m_data);
            m_data = temp;
            m_size = size;
        }
    };

    void push(T t)
    {
        resize(m_size + 1);
        m_data[m_size - 1] = std::move(t);
    }

    myVec<T>& operator=(myVec<T> rhs)
    {
        std::swap(m_data, rhs.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size, rhs.m_size);
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

That said, you should consider adding an `m_capacity` member to your class so you can reduce when you need to reallocate the array:

```
template<class T>
class myVec
{
    T *m_data = nullptr;
    unsigned m_size = 0;
    unsigned m_capacity = 0;

public:
    ...

    myVec() = default;

    myVec(const myVec<T> &src)
    {
        if (src.m_size)
        {
            reserve(src.m_size);

            for(unsigned i = 0; i < src.m_size; ++i)
                new (&m_data[i]) T(src.m_data[i]);

            m_size = src.m_size;
        }
    }

    myVec(myVec<T> &&src)
    {
        std::swap(m_data, src.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size, src.m_size);
        std::swap(m_capacity, src.m_capacity);
    }

    ~myVec()
    {
        resize(0);
    }

    void reserve(unsigned capacity)
    {
        if (capacity > m_capacity)
        {
            T *temp = (T*) malloc(capacity * sizeof(T));
            if (!temp) throw std::runtime_error("malloc failed!");

            for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
                new (&temp[i]) T(std::move(m_data[i]));

            free(m_data);
            m_data = temp;
            m_capacity = capacity;
        }
    };

    void resize(unsigned size)
    {
        if (m_size != size)
        {
            if (size < m_size)
            {
                for(unsigned i = m_size; i-- > size; )
                    m_data[i].~T();
            }
            else
            {
                reserve(size);
                for(unsigned i = m_size; i < size; ++i)
                    new(&m_data[i]) T();
            }

            m_size = size;
        }
    };

    void push(T t)
    {
        if (m_size == m_capacity) reserve(m_size > 0 ? m_size * 1.5 : 4);
        new(&m_data[m_size]) T(std::move(t));
        ++m_size;
    }

    myVec<T>& operator=(myVec<T> rhs)
    {
        std::swap(m_data, rhs.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size, rhs.m_size);
        std::swap(m_capacity, rhs.m_capacity);
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: You could still use `realloc` just for the possibility of growing in place (albeit with a useless `memcpy` when that failed).

Comment: To avoid leaks when myVec::resize() is called: m_data needs to be freed before assigning temp

Comment: You also need to: (1) pass an address to placement new, i.e. &m_data[i]. (2) In myVec::resize(), in the first for loop, T's destructor should be called on _data[i], not on _data[i-1]. (3) In myVec::push(), the arg to reserve should be something like this: reserve(m_size > 0 ? m_size*1.5 : 4).
Besides the above simple fixes to make it work, myVec is a good illustrative implementation

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fundamentally and irredeemably wrong to use `realloc` in this way.

Consider, for example, a class that has two members, one of which is a pointer to the other. If you `realloc` an instance of that class, the pointer will no longer point to the other member, breaking it.

Look into placement new and move semantics or look at existing implementations of `std::vector`.

Comment: thanks for the replay, interesting why there is no realloc like function in c++..

Comment: @EliavLouski There's move semantics which does the same thing and more.